# Java Quartz is internally caching jobs and its parameters

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, cron, quartz-scheduler, kettle

I am involved in a project which requires me to create a Job Scheduler using “Quartz Scheduler” to schedule various jobs which in turn trigger Pentaho Kettle transformation(s). Kettle transformations are essentially ETL scripts performing some mundane activities in our case. Am facing a critical issue while running the scheduler:
We have around 10 jobs scheduled using Job Scheduler. For some 3 to 4 specific jobs it’s throwing following exception:

```
Unable to load the job from XML file [/home /transformations/jobs/TestJob.kjb] Unable to read file [file:///home /transformations/jobs/ TestJob.kjb] Could not read from "file:///home /transformations/jobs/TestJob.kjb" because it is a not a file. 

org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.(JobMeta.java:715)

org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta.(JobMeta.java:679)

com. XYZ.transformation.jobs.impl.JobBootstrapImpl.executeJob(JobBootstrapImpl.java:115)

com. XYZ.transformation.jobs.impl.JobBootstrapImpl.startJobsExecution(JobBootstrapImpl.java:100)

com. XYZ.transformation.jobs.impl.QuartzJobsScheduler.executeInternal(QuartzJobsScheduler.java:25)

org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.QuartzJobBean.execute(QuartzJobBean.java:86)

org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:223)

org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)
```

Weird thing is that, upon verifying the specified path i.e. “/home /transformations/jobs/TestJob.kjb”, file is present and I am able to read it. Moreover the Job runs successfully and does all the things which it is supposed to, yet throws the exception detailed above.

After observing closely, I strongly feel that Quartz is internally caching jobs and/or its parameters. We do load certain parameters required for the job to execute after it is triggered. Would it be possible to delete/purge the cache used by Quartz? I also tried killing all the java processes running on the box (thinking that it may kill Quartz itself, as Quartz is being run within java process) and restarting quartz and its jobs afresh, but couldn’t make it work as expected. It still stores the old parameters somewhere perhaps in some cache.

Versions used –

1. Spring Framework (spring-core & spring-beans) - 3.0.6.RELEASE
2. Quertz Scheduler - 1.8.6
3. Platform – Redhat Linux - 2.6.18-308.el5
4. Pentaho kettle – Spoon Stable Release – 4.3.0

Answer (score 0):

I will do in this way:

1. Ensure that the Pentaho Job can run in standalone first with a shell script, java service wrapper or whatever
2. In the Quartz Job, then use Quartz's NativeJob to call the same standalone script

Just my two cents

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have an extra space in the path.

/home /transformations/jobs/TestJob.kjb

Between the e of home and the /

Remove that space, I can't possibly believe you actually have a home directory called "home "!!